# JSP hot/auto deploy not working in JBoss ES 6.2 w/ Liferay 6.2

Tags: jsp, jboss, liferay, hotdeploy

I working on a project that is using Liferay 6.2 on JBoss ES 6.2 (JBoss AS 7.x, from what I have read).  I am using the Liferay created ANT scripts to do my deploys, but for some strange reason the JSP file changes do not get picked up.  Everytime I make a change to a JSP I have to shut down JBoss, nuke the files under standalone/tmp, then restart JBoss.  Java changes seem to deploy just fine.  For instance, if I add a log message to my portlet code and update some HTML text in my JSP and deploy the portlet project, I see my log entry immediately but the page text change is not there.  Needless to say, having to restart the whole app server for every UI change/tweak is greatly diminishing my productivity.

I don't know what information would be needed to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if you have timezone issues when you deploy your project:: If the timestamps on the JSPs are 1 hour too old (because of a bad timezone) and the previous deployment/test was 10 minutes ago, the JSP might have been compiled 10 minutes ago - that's still 50 min after the (updated) jsp's date, so no need to recompile.

I hope this timezone-explanation wasn't too messy and is understandable.

Comment: where would I go to check?  I mean, the system is set for Eastern, but it was originally Mountain time.  Is there a setting in JBoss somewhere?

Comment: check if jboss has the temporary compiled jsps somewhere and compare their timestamps. tomcat has them in its "/work" folder

Comment: Right, I'll do that.  But I can already tell you my JBoss startup reports that the timezone is being set to GMT, so I am 99.9% sure that's the issue, but I can't figure out how to get it to not be GMT.

Comment: Check the timestamps in the deployed code as well - if your appserver is configured correctly, maybe your CI-server (or wherever you build the deployables) isn't. It's a while since I've seen this in real life, but I've definitely seen it. Of course, it could also be something else...

Comment: So, I did a simple test:  since JBoss was reporting in the JAVA_OPTS that the timezone was GMT, I simply set my workstation to GMT.  Violla!  JSP hot deploys work fine now.  I cannot determine where JBoss is getting the -Duser.timezone=GMT, though.  As I said, I have searched all the files I can find, but nothing.

Answer (score 1):

For me adding the following lines in `standalone.xml` worked.

```
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:web:2.2" default-virtual-server="default-host" native="false">
        <configuration>
            <jsp-configuration development="true" />
        </configuration>
        ...
    </subsystem>
```